# How to configure Beam to use s3 as artifacts dir?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

How do I configure the artifacts_dir so that i can use s3 for it?

According to the [doc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/_modules/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.html):

> The location to store staged artifact files. Any Beam-supported file system is allowed. If unset, the local temp dir will be used.

However, I've tried to configure `--artifacts_dir=s3a://my-bucket/` as a regular beam pipeline option, but doesn't seems to work, the job still using the default `/tmp/beam-artifact-staging`.

Given that my pipeline also using the KafkaIO, I've also tried to put the same option when launching the expansion service. Then the entire expansion service won't even able to start.

I am currently using Apache Beam 2.41.0 with Flink 1.14.5 via the `ProtableRunner`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to run a Python multi-language pipeline (that uses Java) and use this option ? Can you simplify and try just a Python pipeline ? Expansion service cannot take this parameter currently, but if you are running a Python pipeline, you should just have to specify as a Python pipeline option (not as a Java expansion service option).

Comment: i cannot just use a python pipeline, because we need to use KafkaIO.  I've tested only configure the python pipeline only, but the jar is still being put into the /tmp/beam-artifact-staging and not s3.